# (How) can I use BackBlaze to synch a few key data files between Windows & Android?

Tags: windows, android, sync, backblaze

Can I install the BackBlaze client on both Windows and Android, and then synch files, no matter which device updates them?

I am thinking of only a very few key data files, such as my Keepass password data file, a To-Do list, etc.

If so, would I have to move them all to a single directory (and tweak the settings of whichever app uses them to save to/load from that directory)?

Hmm, that sounds like a good idea on the Android side, since the files are primarily created by Windows, and I don't necessarily want to duplicate that directory structure on Android. Maybe I could use symlinks from Windows, in that common directory, to the real data files?

Comment: Backblaze is not a sync solution, it's a backup solution. To extract saved data you must sign in, supply the encryption password, select & download the required data.

Comment: @Tetsujin Then, the answer is no, and you can post that as an answer. I no longer trust DropBox, after it managed to overwrite the most recent copy of my code with an older version from my server.  Since I already subscribe to BackBlaze, I wondered if I can use that. Since it seems that I cannot, I have asked a [question on S/w recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/77862/cloud-backup-synch-software-that-will-follow-symlinks-so-that-i-dont-have-to) looking for such a service.

Comment: Maybe you can think to some self-hosted cloud system (also referred as home cloud systems). E.g. give it a look to nextcloud apps...

Comment: Isn't Git supposed to be for code synchronisation & versioning? You don't really want a strict sync, because if you break one copy you just broke them all. ...i'm speaking here as someone who accidentally trashed something on iCloud sync yesterday & even with 3 distinct backups across three separate 'media', on- & off-line (including Backblaze), it still took me 30 hours to *almost* fully recover to where I was before.

Comment: Upvote for the lateral thinking with GIt, but it's more than just code . Also, I would prefer to auto-encrypt on my PC before uploading to the cloud. Feel free to contribute to to my S/w recommendations question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I install the BackBlaze client on both Windows and Android, and then synch files, no matter which device updates them?

Not possible. BackBlaze backs up devices, but doesn't sync them. After BackBlaze backs up a file from device A, the only way to retrieve this file in device B is to use BackBlaze restore via the BackBlaze website:

[image]